# Android Support Library Bump 27.1.0 Fails to Compile Due to `kapt`

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library, kapt

I'm trying to upgrade my Android app's support library dependency from 27.0.2 to 27.1.0. 
When doing so and attempting to assemble the app, the compilation fails.

For kotlin databinding I'm using: `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"`

For kotlin I'm using: `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.30"`

Here's the stack trace that results when trying to compile

```
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.Open stacktrace Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more
> detailsClose stacktrace at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
> at
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptTask.compile(KaptTask.kt:124)
> at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
> at
> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
> at
> org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> at
> org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

I believe the issue is kotlin, considering the compile exception is caught in `KaptTask.kt:124`. Yet I cannot determine what needs to be changed in my application to successfully compile.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Finally fixed, see my updated answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the compilation error was due to changes in the support library (in this case revolving around changes to `@IntDef` in kotlin no longer requiring a Long to be passed in, instead requiring an Int).

I wasn't originally able to find this compilation error because it was hidden in the 100+ databinding errors that were thrown by Android Studio. (I use databinding pretty heavily in my app)

To fix this, I increased the maximum error count shown in the gradle logs, by adding this to my app's gradle file:

```
// Works for both java and kotlin
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        // Increase the max count of errors from annotation processors.
        // Default is 100.
        option("-Xmaxerrs", 1000)
    }
}
```

This increases the max count of errors for BOTH kotlin and java, whereas another implementation I've seen does not. Shown here:

```
// Only works for java
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "1000"
        }
    }
}
```

This will ONLY increase the max error count for java, NOT kotlin. Just an FYI.

Anyways, with the error count increased, I was able to find the very useful compilation errors at the bottom, which were actually the problem. These were simple enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to try

```
implementation org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.30
```

from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: Why? Could you elaborate?

Comment: You may like to have a read from the Standard library section in https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/09/kotlin-1-2-beta-is-out/

Comment: Unfortunately using jdk instead of jre did not resolve my issue. Thanks for the suggestion.